# Enforce that a variable can be assigned only once

Tags: dart

Let's say I have this code inside a class:

```
String _str;
String get str => _str;
void set(String s) {
    assert(_str == null);
    _str = s;
}
```

How could I ensure that only the setter and getter have access to _str? This would be to prevent that anything inside the same class would be unable to bypass the condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way. In Dart privacy is per library. Everything within one library can read/write everything else within that library.

I would go for

```
String __str;
String get str => __str;
void set(String s) {
    assert(__str == null);
    __str = s;
}
```

and just never access members that start with two underscores except from within the associated getter/setter pairs.
I do this sometimes when I want a private field with private getter setter like

```
String __str;
String get _str => __str;
void _set(String s) {
    assert(_str == null);
    __str = s;
}
```

A weird workaround would be to create a class in another library like

```
class StringProperty {
  String _str;
  String get value => _str;
  void set value(String s) {
    assert(_str == null);
    _str = s;
  }
}
```

and then use it in your library like

```
final StringProperty str = new StringProperty();
```

You can then access the value then like

```
str.value = 'abc';
print(str.value);
```

and in no other way.